# Cannot import name 'six' from 'pip._vendor' inside virtual environment on Debian

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, debian, virtualenv

On Debian/Bullseye (testing) the provided `python3` moved from 3.7 to 3.8.

To provide 3.7 to projects still using it, I install a fresh [`python3.7.7`](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-377/) in *userland* ([this way](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/350985/280824)).

Now I want to use it, let's re-create a virtual environment :

```sh
$ virtualenv --clear -p ~/pythonroot/bin/python3.7 .venv
created virtual environment CPython3.7.7.final.0-64 in 98ms
  creator CPython3Posix(dest=/home/user/git/repo/.venv, clear=True, global=False)
  seeder FromAppData(download=False, pip=latest, setuptools=latest, wheel=latest, pkg_resources=latest, via=copy, app_data_dir=/home/user/.local/share/virtualenv/seed-app-data/v1.0.1.debian)
  activators BashActivator,CShellActivator,FishActivator,PowerShellActivator,PythonActivator,XonshActivator
```

`pip` fails to run :

```sh
$ source .venv/bin/activate;pip -V
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/git/repo/.venv/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main
  File "/home/user/git/repo/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
  File "/home/user/git/repo/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/autocompletion.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
  File "/home/user/git/repo/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main_parser.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli import cmdoptions
  File "/home/user/git/repo/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/cmdoptions.py", line 24, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.progress_bars import BAR_TYPES
  File "/home/user/git/repo/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/progress_bars.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._vendor import six
ImportError: cannot import name 'six' from 'pip._vendor' (/home/user/git/repo/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/__init__.py)
zsh: exit 1     pip -
```

Re-create again a virtual environment, with explicit `pip` version :

```sh
$ deactivate
$ virtualenv --clear --pip 19 -p ~/pythonroot/bin/python3.7 .venv
created virtual environment CPython3.7.7.final.0-64 in 1380ms
  creator CPython3Posix(dest=/home/user/git/repo/.venv, clear=True, global=False)
  seeder FromAppData(download=False, pip=19, setuptools=latest, wheel=latest, pkg_resources=latest, via=copy, app_data_dir=/home/user/.local/share/virtualenv/seed-app-data/v1.0.1.debian)
  activators BashActivator,CShellActivator,FishActivator,PowerShellActivator,PythonActivator,XonshActivator
$ source .venv/bin/activate;pip -V
pip 20.1.1 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip (python 3.8)
```

Now `pip` runs.

*Question* : Why the `pip` version used is an other version that I set on virtual environment creation ?

---

**Edit** : I Edit the title : this looks like a path issue…

I added a python3.7 installation *system-wide* :

```sh
$ python3 -m pip -V
pip 20.1.1 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip (python 3.8)
$ python3.7 -m pip -V
pip 19.2.3 from /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
$ ./pylocal/bin/python3.7 -m pip -V
pip 19.2.3 from /home/user/pylocal/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
$ python3 -c 'from pip._vendor import six'
$ python3.7 -c 'from pip._vendor import six'
$ ./pylocal/bin/python3.7 -c 'from pip._vendor import six'
```

but inside virtual environment, `pip` is still broken :

```sh
$ virtualenv --clear --python python3.7 .venv37
created virtual environment CPython3.7.7.final.0-64 in 102ms
  creator CPython3Posix(dest=/home/user/.venv37, clear=True, global=False)
  seeder FromAppData(download=False, pip=latest, setuptools=latest, wheel=latest, pkg_resources=latest, via=copy, app_data_dir=/home/user/.local/share/virtualenv/seed-app-data/v1.0.1.debian)
  activators BashActivator,CShellActivator,FishActivator,PowerShellActivator,PythonActivator,XonshActivator
$ source .venv37/bin/activate
(.venv37)$ which python
/home/user/.venv37/bin/python
(.venv37)$ python -V
Python 3.7.7
(.venv37)$ python -c 'from pip._vendor import six'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'six' from 'pip._vendor' (/home/user/.venv37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/__init__.py)
zsh: exit 1     python -c 'from pip._vendor import six'
```

Comment: Hum the last creation did not work as expected too… `pip` is not inside my virtual environment

Comment: As `venv` can create a virtual environment, I [create an issue](https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/issues/1860) on `pypa/virtualenv` to gives feedback.